# Pack hex string using struct module?

Tags: python, string, hex

I want to pack a hex string with python pack.
Here is my code:

```
import struct
query='430401005001'
q= ('%x' % int(query, 16)).decode('hex').decode('utf-8')
qpacked=struct.pack('6s',str(q))
```

Query is a hex string. 
The code does not work if I change the string to '53040600d0010100' and change 6s to 8s.
Is there any better way to pack such a hex string?

Comment: Why are you decoding arbitrary binary data as UTF-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string gets truncated because you're telling it you want to pack it up to length 6 (`6s`). You'll have to either raise that number, or work around your string getting truncated.

Also, stop juggling with the encoding of your string, just `query.decode('hex')` should suffice.

Comment: I did change 6 to 12, but python error is 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0